# How can I test something that needs to occur in the future with rspec & sidekiq?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

Users can checkout from my Rails storefront, thereby creating an `order`. Assuming the user doesn't cancel, I want to create a repeat order a month later.

Because I believe it is better to look for things to do now rather than schedule things to occur in the future, I want to have something looking for orders that need to be processed and creating a Sidekiq job for each occurrence. Each of these jobs will create a new order with the same contents as the previous order.

Because I want to use TDD, before I go adding Sidekiq to my project or implementing this functionality, I want to write an rspec test that tells me that my jobs are being enqueued at the proper time. I'll then implement the enqueueing and move on to writing a spec that confirms that the job actually creates a new order, at which point I'll go and implement that.

My question is how should I implement the test to ensure that the jobs are being created?

I see that `ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers` has replaced Timecop, so I'm all for using that. My first thought would be to do this:

1. Create order
2. Fast forward a month
3. Confirm a job was created to process the order that needs to be handled

But I am pretty sure there won't be a job run in this case, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `have_enqueued_job` tester in the [rspec-sidekiq](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq) gem

Example from their docs

```
AwesomeJob.perform_async 'Awesome', true
# test with...
expect(AwesomeJob).to have_enqueued_job('Awesome', true)
```

*edit*

In response to comments. Use instead:

```
expect { AwesomeJob.perform_async 'Awesome', true }.to have_enqueued_job('Awesome', true)
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I am running into the error `have_enqueued_job and enqueue_job only support block expectations` that spits out because I'm not specifically trying to create this job in my spec - my goal is to test that I have the required pieces in place such that, come a month later, the job has been enqueued.

Comment: How about writing unit tests for the code? Or use  mocks

Comment: I am all for unit tests and mocks, but I still need an integration test that makes sure the system is working because this is business-critical.

Comment: ```expect { AwesomeJob.perform_async 'Awesome', true }.to have_enqueued_job('Awesome', true)``` The content which will get executed should be in the block. ```{}``` or ```do end```

Comment: expect { AwesomeJob }
instead of expect(AwesomeJob)